# add_subdirectory twice with different properties

Tags: cmake

I want to use a library added via `add_subdirectory` with different compilation properties:

```
add_subdirectory(fmt)

target_link_libraries(<my-64bit-target> fmt::fmt) # fmt should be compiled for x86-64 with -m64 flag
target_link_libraries(<my-32bit-target> fmt::fmt) # fmt should be compiled for x86-64 with -m32 flag
```

Is this possible without interfering with the external library CMakeList.txt?

Comment: No, because it would create two targets with the same name.

Comment: Is there any way to clone a target and modify it?

Comment: You could possibly hack around this by using fmt in header-only mode, which should mean that it will take on whatever flags of the sources using it.